# Switch case with String and Enum

Tags: java, switch-statement

TiposDeOperacoes is an enum and operacao is a String, how can I use Enums in this case, since VSCode tells me it's a type mismatch?

```
    public float Calculo(String operacao, float valor1, float valor2){
            float resultado = 0;
    
            switch (operacao) {
                case TiposDeOperacoes.SOMA:
                    
                    break;
            
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

TiposDeOperacoes.SOMA.name() also gives me "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Comment: To match types you can convert String to enum value with `switch (TiposDeOperacoes.valueOf(operacao)){ `, but be sure that enum contains such value, otherwise `valueOf` will throw `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score -1):

## tl;dr

```
Mode.valueOf( "ADD" )  // returns `Mode.ADD` object.
```

… or:

```java
switch ( modeText )
        {
            case "adding" -> Mode.ADD;
            case "minus" , "subtraction" -> Mode.SUBTRACT;
            case "multiplication" , "multiplying" -> Mode.MULTIPLY;
            case "division" -> Mode.DIVIDE;
            default -> throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected mode text: " + modeText );
        };
```

## Details

The ideal solution is for the method to take an enum object rather than mere text. If you are testing for enums, then pass enums. Using mere text is fragile, error-prone.

```
 public float Calculo( TiposDeOperacoes tiposDeOperacoes , float valor1 , float valor2 ) { … }
```

But if you insist on strings, you can ask the enum object for its name by calling [`Enum#name`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#name()).

```
switch ( operacao ) 
    case TiposDeOperacoes.SOMA.name() : …
```

But you do not need a `switch` for that behavior. Just call [`Enum#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)).

```
TiposDeOperacoes tiposDeOperacoes = TiposDeOperacoes.valueOf( operacao ) ;
```

### Separation of concerns

Learn about [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), with regard to software design.

I suggest you call one method to figure out the mapping between string input and the enum object, and a second method taking an enum object that performs your calculation. Two jobs: (a) mapping text to enum, and (b) performing calculation, should be two separate methods.

For example, let's define an enum.

```java
package work.basil.example.maths;

public enum Mode { ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE; }
```

And define a `Calculator` class with our core business logic.

```java
package work.basil.example.maths;

public class Calculator
{
    public float calculate ( final Mode mode , final float x , final float y )
    {
        float result =
                switch ( mode )
                        {
                            case ADD -> ( x + y );
                            case SUBTRACT -> ( x - y );
                            case MULTIPLY -> ( x * y );
                            case DIVIDE -> ( x / y );
                        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

And an app to put those above classes into action.

```java
package work.basil.example.maths;

public class CalcApp
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        CalcApp calcApp = new CalcApp();
        calcApp.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        String modeText = "minus";
        float inputX = 42.0f;
        float inputY = 7.0f;

        Mode mode = this.modeForText( modeText );
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        float result = calculator.calculate( mode , inputX , inputY );
        System.out.println( "result = " + result );
    }

    private Mode modeForText ( String modeText )
    {
        Mode mode =
                switch ( modeText )
                        {
                            case "adding" -> Mode.ADD;
                            case "minus" , "subtraction" -> Mode.SUBTRACT;
                            case "multiplication" , "multiplying" -> Mode.MULTIPLY;
                            case "division" -> Mode.DIVIDE;
                            default -> throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected mode text: " + modeText );
                        };
        return mode;
    }
}
```

---

By the way, FYI, as of Java 16 an enum can be defined locally, within a method. This came from work on the [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature.

Comment: `TiposDeOperacoes.SOMA.name()` would be better.

Comment: @Stewart Good point! I made the change.

Comment: I'm using String because I get this info through a path like:
"http://localhost:8080/calculadora_Single?op=soma&v1=1-&v2=20", where op is the operacao

Comment: Doesn't `case` require *compilation time constant* as value which prevents `.name()` from being used?

Comment: @CaioHenriquePortella Very well, but generally best for a method to focus on a single responsibility. So I suggest you call one method to figure out the mapping between string input and the enum object, and a second method taking an enum object that performs your calculation. Two jobs: (a) mapping text to enum, and (b) performing calculation, should be two separate methods.

Comment: @BasilBourque makes total sense, thank you so much!